# quasar q-select infinite scroll

Tags: select, infinite-scroll, quasar

How to apply infinite scroll on q-select? I see there is "virtual-scroll" event which return this `json`,

```
{index: 11, from: 0, to: 11, direction: 'increase', ref: VueComponent}
```

But the problem is when you are using mouse and scrolling, it is not updating the index parameter in returned data, and the index is always the position of the last greyed item, but with keyboard it is working as you are always moving the greyed item in selected list.

How to know scroll is near end to trigger fetch data? Should I take another approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution,

```
<q-select>
    <template v-slot:option="scope">
         <q-infinite-scroll @load="onLoad" :offset="25">
          <q-item v-bind="scope.itemProps" v-on="scope.itemEvents">
          </q-item>
         </q-infinite-scroll>
    </template>
</q-select>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**